# React-query : Many fetch requests common practice?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am getting my hands back on React and got in touch with React-query and if there is no misunderstanding from my side, it feels like the common practice of using React-query completely ignores the number of network requests. Until now (junior-level), I have tried to be economical with the number of network requests which is why I am struggling to "accept" the way I understand React-query atm.

In many tutorials and docs I see people do something like that:

`const dogsQuery = useQuery({queryKey: ['dogs'], queryFn: fetchDogs});`

and

```
const createDogMutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: createDog,  
    onSuccess: () => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries('dogs');  
    },
});
```

So it basically means that when I create a new dog, I would refetch all dogs. And lets say I'd have an additional useQuery such as `filteredDogsQuery`, they would get fetched again as well. And if I do it this way consistently, I'd apply the same schema when I update/delete a dog. I'd always refetch everything that is related to the 'dogs' queryKey. And in addition to that, some dogs would get fetched twice, e.g. when they are among all dogs (which of course they are) and among the filtered dogs.

The way I did things before was when I create a new entity, I'd receive the created entity in the response and add it to my local store. I saw in the React-query docs that you can manually update the cache instead of refetching everything, but I do not see a lot of people doing so.

Because of react query, I'm now also wondering whether it's even a bad thing to have so many (partially) unnecessary requests and whether I've tried to be frugal for more or less no reason so far :D

So, am I right? Is it just common practice right now and you mostly just ignore the number of network requests as long as everything works stable and smooth?

Comment: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/framework/react/guides/optimistic-updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The way I did things before was when I create a new entity, I'd receive the created entity in the response and add it to my local store.

That's a great solution, and you can do that too in react query. If you're able to calculate the new data without calling the server again, you can update the cache yourself:

```
onSuccess: (data, variables, context) => {
  queryClient.setQueryData(["dogs"], prev => {
    // Calculate the new value and return it. For example if you are adding to an array:
    if (!prev) {
      return [data];
    } else {
      return [...prev, data];
    }
  });
}
```

In the above code, `data` is the response from the mutation, `variables` is the data that was passed into your mutation function, and `context` is an optional extra piece of data that's sometimes needed if you want to pass some data between your `onMutate` and `onSuccess` functions.

If you can't predict the new values, you can fall back to invalidating the query like in the examples. I suspect the tutorials you're reading start with this because it's easy and always works. But it's not necessarily the best, since it makes the user wait longer and use more bandwidth.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!

So if I understand you correctly, you'd generally rather update the cache locally using `setQueryData` or `setQueriesData` if you can predict the new values instead of just invalidating a query? Or are there some cases where you'd still just go for the invalidation?

Comment: I generally prefer updating the cache when possible for the extra performance. But it does come with a small risk of bugs. If i don't update the cache correctly, i might have slightly different data than what the server would send me. Or maybe the update code is correct when i implement it, but changes to the server logic make it become incorrect later. So for complicated stuff, i'm more likely to invalidate and thus refetch. Your example of adding and removing dogs is not complicated though, so i would update the cache.